# ReactJs, dropdown menu with buttons or should I use something else?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drop-down-menu, menu

I have an image in the center of my screen and have found a way to use button to change the image, but I want to create a dropdown menu instead so it looks neater. I'm fairly new to React so I'm looking a lot of things up and finding it a bit hard to understand.. this is the following code I have

```
const setImage = () =>{
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(assets.apple)

 return(
     <div className="Fruits">
         <img src={selected} alt='image.png' />
         <div className="FruitOptions">
          <button onClick={() => setSelected(assets.apple)}>apple</button>
          <button onClick={() => setSelected(assets.orange)}>orange</button>
          <button onClick={() => setSelected(assets.watermelon)}>watermelon</button>
         </div>
     </div>
 )
}
```

I found this in the react bootstrap docs and wasn't sure if this would be a proper way to do it..

```
<DropdownButton id="dropdown-basic-button" title="Dropdown button">
  <Dropdown.Item onClick={() => setSelected(assets.apples)}>apples</Dropdown.Item>
  <Dropdown.Item onClick={() => setSelected(assets.orange)}>oranges</Dropdown.Item>
  <Dropdown.Item onClick={() => setSelected(assets.watermelons)}>watermelons</Dropdown.Item>
</DropdownButton>
```

Comment: It doesn't really make a question in my opinion

Answer (score 0):

It's a good way to achieve it, but i prefer to use the `Ant-Design`, you can find more information in `https://ant.design/`.